# Can we run simple html file on our machine by turning off IIS server?

Tags: html, iis, webserver

This is a very basic question but wanted to confirm that if we have a simple html file which we want to run on browser, Do we need to turn on IIS server or simple html file does not need any server and browser takes care of it?

Thank you
HP

Comment: I don't want to sound too scornful but you could have simply tried opening an htm file on your machine to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "run", but you can load any HTML file locally by opening it in the browser.

All javascript and HTML will work as expected, no serverside code will though.

If your links are relative links, they will also work as expected.

Comment: Actually my question here is "Does IIS Server plays any role in opening html file?" , I know that I can open simple html file directly but just for curiosity I wanted to know If IIS server has any role when html file renders into window.

Comment: @HPK - Well. Where do the files "live"? If on a _remote_ computer that can only be accessed via HTTP, then you do need _a_ web server to serve up static files, IIS or otherwise.

Comment: @Odeo : Files are located in my local machine only. If I want to open a local html file, then IIS server is required?

Comment: @HPK - As I answered, no it isn't. If you use a [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), IIS will not be involved.

Comment: @HPK - "If IIS server has any role when html file renders into window". Apart from _serving up the file_, no. Once the browser has loaded and parsed the file (and all linked resources) the role of IIS is over.

Comment: Thanks Odeo. It answers my question.

Comment: Oh Sorry. It is typing mistake :( . Thanks Oded.